# Action route optional id parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I'm trying to create a controller action with optional /id parameter like so:

1. default `http://localhost/tasks`
2. with id `http://localhost/tasks/42`

Here is the controller and the action:
What I tried to do was to use the **route attribute** on the action

```
public class TasksController : AsyncController
{
    [Route("tasks/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This worked but only with the id parameter set in the url, but the default page `/tasks` throws a not found error, alternatively when using `[Route("tasks")]` without the id, the default page works, but when id is set, a not found error is thrown again. I also tried `[Route("tasks/{id ?}")]` to mark the id as optional parameter but it didn't work.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: @JohnSaunders But when searching for asp.net related questions most of them had ASP.NET MVC in the title and it definitely made it easier to spot and find. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I don't know how you're searching. I just searched http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net?sort=newest&pageSize=50, and it is not the case. I strongly suggest you check the link I included. The tags already include this information, so you  don't need to waste space in your title which could be used to give people a better idea of what your problem is.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I meant google search, it was more obvious. I checked the link too and I get the point.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make a URI parameter optional by adding a question mark to the route parameter. If a route parameter is optional, you must define a default value for the method parameter.

Set the default value on the action method and add question mark to end of route param.

```
[Route("tasks/{id?}")]
public ActionResult Index(string id =null)
```

Comment: This seemed to work fine, I tried something similiar already but i had a space before the ?. I have other problem with my code when on ajax call to this controllers custom action it seems like the index action is called too. But it probably doesnt have to do with this right? Anyway I think this is the best answer

Comment: Good answer (+1), but I came up against this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31256829/action-route-optional-id-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You have to check for the value of the parameter in your controller:

```
public class PlansController : AsyncController
{
    [Route("tasks/{id}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        if(id == null)
        {
             return View("ViewName");
        }
        else
        {
             //Query DB and get model for the view
             return View("ViewName", Model);
        }
    }
}
```

Since string is nullable by default you don't have to worry about user passing a null and getting yellow screen of error.

Comment: I dont think this would help, I already had this part in my code but the problem was the route

Comment: How was this downvoted? only difference from accepted is id is being set to null from the start?

Comment: I didn't downvote so I don't know, but as I said the problem with this approach was the route `[Route("tasks/{id}")]` which needed the ? to be an optional parameter

Comment: If you set up your route config correctly you can set that parameter as optional regardless of controller  'routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );'

Comment: Idk how to edit comments but the optional id value is set in route config

Comment: But in mvc 5 u can set the route config right in the action or class declaration just for that only one since its easier and cleaner

Answer (score -1):

```
public class TestController : AsyncController
{
    [Route("tasks/{id?}")]
    public ActionResult Index(string id)
    {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = id ?? "Empty" };
    }

    [Route("task/{id=demo}")]
    public ActionResult Task(string id)
    {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = id ?? "DemoEmpty" };
    }
}
```

i just test it,it works fine

Comment: which one you don not understand? `ContentResult`?`{id=demo}`?`{id?}`?

Comment: `ContentResult`, I know `id?` is an optional parameter and `id=demo` is probably the same as `if (id == "demo") {}..`